# realtime clock with vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've written a small clock component for one of my projects,
but I didn't get the value for my clock refreshed.

A short extract of my code:

```
    time() {
      let now = new Date();
      let hour = this.zeroPadding(now.getHours());
      let minute = this.zeroPadding(now.getMinutes());
      let second = this.zeroPadding(now.getSeconds());

      console.log(hour.toString() + minute.toString() + second.toString())
      if(!this.realtime)
        return this.value
      else
        return hour.toString() + ":" + minute.toString() + ":" + second.toString()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.time()
    }, 1000)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    clearInterval(this.polling)
  }
```

Does anyone finde the mistake?
Did I understand the polling wrong?

Greetings,
Matthias

Comment: Please add the full code with your template. The `time` method returns a string, but where do you use it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The time value that you want to display needs to be a data / computed property so that it's reactive and Vue can track it. Concise way to do it:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      interval: null,
      time: null
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  },
  created() {
    // update the time every second
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      // Concise way to format time according to system locale.
      // In my case this returns "3:48:00 am"
      this.time = Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language, {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        second: 'numeric'
      }).format()
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```